# How to stop users from accessing my web application folders and files by typing url in address bar?

Tags: asp.net, html

I am using my own authentication method by cookies and username and password verification from database but when I debug my application i can access any folder and image, pdf etc. type files by directly typing the url of that without Log-In. So i want to all these type of unauthorized access to folders and files both to be redirected to default.aspx page.
please help me.

Comment: Use `<authorization>` tag in your web.config, along with `<location>`tag.

Comment: can you please explain this with codes i am not familiar with this tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
       <location path="[subdir1]">
            <system.web>
              <authorization>
                            <deny users ="?" />
                    <allow users ="*" />
              </authorization>
            </system.web>
       </location>
```

change the `[subdir]` to the folder you want to protect. For more info see [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871)

Comment: can u tell what user = * and ? do here, do i need to change these with my own data.

Comment: @user1306589, no you don't need to change this, this is allowing access to all authenticated users.

Comment: how can i deny access to multiple directories by writing only single code like above or i have to write codes for each directory specifying path. please reply.

Comment: @if you want to restrict it for the whole application then remove the `<location>` tag, for a few folders, you need to do it seperately.

Comment: i did the restriction for the images folder but now my application itself cannot access images folder and not showing images on webpages.help me.

Comment: @user1306589, the images folder is usually a public folder, why you want to restrict the images folder? for resources that you want to keep secure move them to a different place, since you can't allow for some and deny for some resources in a single folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13249/discussion-between-user1306589-and-furqan)

Answer (score 0):

**Try these**

1. Use Asp.net Authentication, for more info [Go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx)
2. Use global.asax file beginrequest event, do your custom code there to check valid user, for more info [Go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx)